# How to find nearby objects in Django, based on location. It seems annotate does not consider model fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying find nearby objects in Django based on location.

I have used this query:

`near_objs = MyModel.objects.all().annotate(distance=great_circle((given_latitude, given_longitude), (F('latitude'), F('longitude'))).km)`

But I am getting error `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'F'`.

If I don't use`F()`, it throws error`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'latitude'`

It seems annotate() does not consider `('latitude')` and `('longitude')` as model fields